# Extract the number and following letter from regex

Tags: python, regex

I have many strings referring to monetary values, such as `$15K`, `USD20M`, `€1.8k` , etc
Now I need to extract the number and the multiplier (K,k, M or m) in order to process the data.

I came up with the following regex:

```
[\${1}|€{1}][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?[M|K|k|m]
```

But I'm not sure how to extract each of the subparts of the expression and return them back to my Python code as variables, so for `$15K`, I would want:

```
currency='$'
ammount=15
multiplier='K'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide some sample inputs.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary he did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
In [1]: import re 

In [2]: re.match(r'(?P<currency>\D+)(?P<amount>\d+(\.\d+)?)(?P<multiplier>[mMkK])', '$15k').groupdict()
Out[2]: {'amount': '15', 'currency': '$', 'multiplier': 'k'}
```

Not like it's really necessary in Python, though, when you can just do

```
currency, amount, _, multiplier =  re.match(r'(\D+)(\d+(\.\d+)?)([mMkK])', '$1.5k').groups()
```

or even simpler

```
currency, amount, multiplier = re.match(r'(\D+)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([mMkK])', '$1.5k').groups()
```

Comment: Doesn't handle the `€1.8k` case.

Comment: @Mark thanks, added a fix, also not perfect though, but probably enough.

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
In [68]: lis= ["$15K", "USD20","$1.5K"]

In [69]: l=lambda x:re.findall(r"(\$|USD)(\d*\.\d+|\d+)([MKkm])?",x)
                                    |          |           |     
                                    ^          ^           ^
                                   currency   amt          multiplier
In [70]: map(l,lis)
Out[70]: [[('$', '15', 'K')], [('USD', '20', '')], [('$', '1.5', 'K')]]
```

Comment: The `|` inside the `[]` are incorrect. Either would work alone though: `[MKkm]` or `M|K|k|m`.

Comment: Now just add the `€` and this will be perfect.